# Calculate grid cells enter/exit timings from overlayed timed route

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector-grid, route

*[QGIS 3.22]*

I have made something that works, but it seems convoluted and I wonder whether there's a more efficient way. What would you say is the best way of going from a list of waypoints with timestamps, to a grid layer where each grid cell that the GPS tracker has crossed is annotated with an interpolated enter and exit timestamp? (The grid cells are smaller than the distances between consecutive waypoints.)

My solution in summary:

- `Points to path` (sort by timestamp field)
- `Create grid` (polygon type) → `Polygons to lines`
- `Split with lines` (route line layer with grid line layer)
- Try to order up the mess. I've been using the `JoinMultipleLines` plugin, not because I want to join multiple lines, but because it seems to order the segments in the right order while doing so.
- Calculate enter/exit timings of each grid cell in the `Field calculator`, and join back by id field to the grid polygon layer.

I have gotten this all to work (yay!), but it involves lots of shuffling around with the field calculator and joins, and there just seems to be too much room for errors for it to be the best way. How would you have done it?

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3.22 there is the option to rasterize 3D lines, interpolating the vertices (*Burn value extracted from the “Z” values of the feature*):
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster

So it seems to me that the best option would be:

- Convert timestamps to integers if they are not.
- Use the *Set Z value* process to translate the field with the timestamp to the Z coordinate of the points.
- Create the path with the *Points to path* process. The Z coordinate of each point will be assigned to its respective vertex within the path.
- Rasterize the paths with the *Rasterize (vector to raster)* process, using the *Burn value extracted from the “Z” values of the feature* option.

Comment: This seems like it could become a solution, however some of it went a little over my head. Two questions: 1) When I tried it, the resulting raster didn't cover all of the path. It covered most, but seemed like a bad fit, missing some parts of the path and creating grid cells slightly next to it in other parts. In the _Set Z value_ process, I entered the timestamp field as expression for _Z value_. Was that not correct? 2) How do I get a table with the annotated enter and exit times for each grid cell? There is no attribute table, and I need id'd grid cells to be able to join fields later.

Comment: I like the idea of this, and since the bounty is about to expire, I will award it to this answer. However, it would be great if we could develop it into a final solution as well :)

Comment: 1) You probably have to include `-at` as an additional command line parameter (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-at), I can edit the answer if that fixes it, otherwise I should see an example path and raster of the problem. The timestamp field as expression for Z value was correct.

Comment: 2) The value (interpolated between vertices) corresponding to the point of the path closest to the center of the pixel will be the one that is recorded. By geometric properties that point is always the middle of the segment, therefore the average between input and output. But these are not calculated nor recorded.